# Convergence of a sequence in a k- dimensional Euclidean metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, call it $(x^{(n)})$. I understand with the most familiar metric $d(x,y) = \left[\sum_{j=1}^{k}(x_j-y_j)^2\right]^{1/2}$ that this sequence will converge if and only if the $i$th term in this sequence converges $(x_{i}^{(n)})$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for every $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$. Is this statement necessarily true for any metric $d$? I know how to prove this statement with the metric stated above but I have no idea how to prove this with any other metric $d$, if this is even possible.

Comment: It is true for any metric induced by a norm since all norms on $\mathbb{R}^k$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Any non-empty set $X$ has the "trivial metric" which is defined as
\begin{align}
d(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $x\neq y$}\\
0&\text{if $x= y$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
A sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to a point $x$ relative to this metric if and only if there exists an $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $x_n=x$. In other words, convergence relative to this metric requires the sequence eventually be constant.

So, a sequence in $\Bbb{R}^2$ (same idea works for any $k$) such as $x_n=\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ does not converge relative to this metric, even though each "component" $x_{n,1}=\frac{1}{n}$  and $x_{n,2}=\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$ relative to the standard metric on $\Bbb{R}$.

---

**Edit in Response to Comment**

Yes, we can also construct counterexamples for the converse; here's the general idea. Let $X$ be a set, $\delta$ a metric on $X$ and $f:X\to X$ a bijection. We can consider the pull-back metric $d=f^*\delta$ on $X$ defined as $d(x,y):=\delta(f(x),f(y))$. We now ask whether it is possible to find a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that

- $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges relative to $d=f^*\delta$ (or equivalently $\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges relative to $\delta$);
- $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge relative to $\delta$.

Such examples are easy to construct in $\Bbb{R}$ (perhaps there are even simpler solutions, but this is the first which came to mind). So, we consider $X=\Bbb{R}$, $\delta$ to be the standard metric and $x_n=(-1)^nn$. This sequence alternates in sign and approaches $\infty$ in magnitude,so it is clear that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge relative to $\delta$ (the standard metric on $\Bbb{R}$).

Now, define $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ by setting $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then, $f$ is a bijection, and $f(x_n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges to $0$ relative to $\delta$, the standard metric. Thus, $x_n$ converges relative to $d=f^*\delta$, which is precisely what we want.

Comment: +1: Do you know of a counterexample for the "converse"? i.e. a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $x_k\to x$ in $d$, but at least one of the components doesn't converge.

Comment: @Jose27 yes, take a look at the edit (I took $k=1$, but clearly using this we can construct examples for any $k$ using the same idea).

Comment: Excellent! I was thinking along similar lines, but didn't think about using $1/x$, it seems so obvious now.